# Multirow without centering (but multiple problems on my way there)

Tags: multirow, vertical

I was wondering how one could use multirow without centering the cell entry vertically. Since I haven't found any questions regarding this, might you please help?

On my way there, I discovered multiple further problems as can be seen in my MWE:

Why does multirow command not work at all in my MWE? What did I miss?

How do I manage line breaks within the first word in a tabular cell? Neither p columns nor P columns (with arraybackslash) seem to work here.

What about that first capital letter getting misplaced? How can one avoid this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

% Based on the class scrreprt by "KOMA-Script", whatever that means. If that doesn't help, please try \documentclass{scrreprt} or one of the usual.
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{x}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb] 
\centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4mm}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|P{6em}|x|P{6em}|}
\hline
\multirow{3}{*} Kommunizierbarkeit & Verständlichkeit und Vermittelbarkeit des Programms für Mitarbeiter und Fahrgäste & \multirow{3}{*} Mitarbeiterbefragung, Fahrgastbefragung, Anzahl der Geschäftsvorfälle in XYZ bzw. an der Schnittstelle ABCD / XYZ \\
& Möglichkeit der Komplexitätsreduktion hinsichtlich der Anweisungen und Informationen für Mitarbeiter und Fahrgäste & \\
& Kommunizierbarkeit der Lösungen & \\\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The newest version of multirow has an optional first argument that specifies the vertical alignment.
2. You must enclose the text of a `\multirow` cell in braces `{}`.
3. TeX doesn't hyphenate the first word of a paragraph. Add \hspace{0pt} in front of it (without intervening spaces) to get the word hyphenated or add manual hyphenation points. 'Kommunizierbarkeit' isn't hyphenated anyway in my LaTeX.
   Also with {*} you don't get linebreaking at all. Use {=} with the new multirow version.
4. The capital letter: see 2.

Table code:

```
 \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|P{6em}|x|P{6em}|}
  \hline
  \multirow[t]{3}{=}{\hspace{0pt}Kommuni\-zier\-bar\-keit} 
    & Verständlichkeit und Vermittelbarkeit des Programms
      für Mitarbeiter und Fahrgäste 
    & \multirow[t]{3}{=}{\hspace{0pt}Mitarbeiterbefragung, 
      Fahrgastbefragung, Anzahl der Geschäftsvorfälle in XYZ
      bzw. an der Schnittstelle ABCD / XYZ} \\
    & Möglichkeit der Komplexitätsreduktion hinsichtlich
      der Anweisungen und Informationen
      für Mitarbeiter und Fahrgäste & \\
    & Kommunizierbarkeit der Lösungen & \\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}
```

[image: Result]

As you can see the third column overflows. Make it a bit wider (e.g. 7em) or add an empty row at the end of the table.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, that already helped a lot! What package am I missing when adding "[t]" or substituting "*" for "=" leads to the error "! Missing number, treated as zero."?

Comment: Bonus question: Can I make this into a longtable without relinquishing the command lines \centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4mm}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}?

Comment: You just need multirow version 2.1.

Comment: You use `tabularx`, so if you want to have a longtable variant of it you can try the packages `ltablex` or `ltxtable`. You have to get rid of the `table` environment, however. And you must make sure that the page break doesn't come in the middle of a multirow cell. See the `multirow` doc. (I don't know if the solution given there works with these other packages.)

Comment: Thanks very much, but how do I get version 2.1? Package documentation does not tell me what package to use (/to install?). Multirow package is already included.

Comment: If your TeX system has a package manager then doing an update should get you the newest version. Otherwise get it from https://www.ctan.org/pkg/multirow and install it in a directory where TeX can find it. For example in the directory where your document is. But using the package manager is the best solution.

Comment: "To generate the .sty files, run the command
   tex multirow.ins
and move the resulting .sty files to a place where LaTeX can find them, preferably
..../tex/latex/multirow" - okay, but where can LaTeX find multirow.ins to run that first command? (Package manager is not working for some reason or the other.)

Comment: `multirow.ins` is part of what you download from CTAN, together with `multirow.dtx`. Put them in a directory, and then run `tex multirow.ins` or `latex multirow.ins` in that directory (using a command line). If you are not familiar with the command line, then maybe you can use your favourite TeX editor/processor, which probably also will work. You can also download a ready-made multirow.sty from `http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/archive/multirow.tar.xz`, maybe that's easier.

But you should find out why your package manager can't do it, as regularly updating your TeX system helps

Comment: In the meantime, I succeeded using the Package Manager, but it first made me delete some packages "no longer needed" (no chance to update multirow solely). Now, I have 99 other problems to deal with before being able to see one single multirow again. But you could not have guessed, so thanks anyways! Will come back to your help when I managed dealing with all other errors eventually...

Answer (score 2):

Pairs of braces were missing for the last argument of `\multirow`. The last but one argument should be set to `\linewidth` (which is the width of the current column). Finally, you can obtain a correct layout enlarging the left and right columns, and letting `\tabcolsep` have its default value (6pt), and adding only  a small adjustment of the position of the multirow contents.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Based on the class scrreprt by "KOMA-Script", whatever that means. If that doesn't help, please try \documentclass{scrreprt} or one of the usual.
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}%
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} %
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{ragged2e}%
 \usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\leavevmode}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{x}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\leavevmode}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|P{9.6em}|x|P{9.6em}|}
\hline
Kommunizierbarkeit & Verständlichkeit und Vermittelbarkeit des Programms für Mitarbeiter und Fahrgäste & \multirow{5}{\linewidth}[-1.2pt]{Mitarbeiterbefragung, Fahrgastbefragung, Anzahl der Geschäftsvorfälle in XYZ bzw. an der Schnittstelle ABCD / XYZ} \\
& Möglichkeit der Komplexitätsreduktion hinsichtlich der Anweisungen und Informationen für Mitarbeiter und Fahrgäste & \\
& Kommunizierbarkeit der Lösungen & \\\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]