# Texts overflows to the right

Tags: formatting

I am trying to create a set of smartphone-readable lecture notes.

I want the page to have almost no margins and the text to be relatively big. I was able to do that and I'm happy with the layout. However, Text overflows to the right and in the bottom. So words extend outside of the page and there is content missing on the page. As you can see in the picture, after section 4 "Vektorräume" there should be much more content but isn't. Also notice the first section name overflowing to the right.

[image]

```
\documentclass[20pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[a5paper,bindingoffset=0in, left=0.3in, right=0.3in, top=0.3in, bottom=0.3in, footskip=.25in]{geometry}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{document}
\section{ThisIsAnOverflowingRootNode}
\section{Vektorrechnung}
\subsection{Längen}
\subsection{Skalarprodukte}

\section{Lineare Gleichungssysteme}
\subsection{Elimination}
\subsection{Matrixoperationen}
\subsection{Inverse Matrizen}
\subsection{Faktorisierung}
\subsection{Transponierte}
\subsection{Permutationen}

\section{Vektorräume}
\subsection{Kern}
\subsection{Rang}
\subsection{Reduzierte Treppenform}
\subsection{Unabhängigkeit}
\subsection{Basis}
\subsection{Dimension}


\section{Orthogonalität}
\subsection{Projektionen}
\subsection{Kleinste Quadrate}
\subsection{Orthogonale Basen und Gram-Schmidt}

\section{Determinanten}
\subsection{Eigenschaften}
\subsection{Permutationen}
\subsection{Kofaktoren}
\subsection{Cramer'sche Regel}
\subsection{Inverse}
\subsection{Volumen}

\section{Eigenwerte und -vektoren}

\section{Anwendungen}
\section{Numerische lineare Algebra}
\section{Komplexe Vektoren und Matrizen}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you have two problems here.  for hyphenation, see [Table column text exceeds column width](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/394081/579).  for the problem that input is cur off abruptly, see [Overfull box and broken pagination with page that contains only section headings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57857)

Comment: @barbarabeeton I couldn't use the information to a high extent, because I'm unexperienced with LaTeX. Can you kindly provide a MWE for my Code? I think that would help me learn

Comment: Add some actual text to each chapter section and subsection. Pagebreak will then be inserted as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Just two problems with your MWE, (thank you for this) which I have tried to fix below (I have marked my additional/changed code with `% -----`

```
% phoneprob.tex SE 424767

\documentclass[20pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[a5paper,bindingoffset=0in, left=0.3in, right=0.3in, top=0.3in, bottom=0.3in, footskip=.25in]{geometry}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\newcommand{\words}{Some text.}   % ----------------------------------
\hyphenation{This-Is-An-Overflowing-Root-Node} % ---------------------

\begin{document}
\section{\hspace{0pt}ThisIsAnOverflowingRootNode} % ---------------------
\section{Vektorrechnung}
\subsection{Längen}
\subsection{Skalarprodukte}

\section{Lineare Gleichungssysteme}
\subsection{Elimination}
\subsection{Matrixoperationen}
\subsection{Inverse Matrizen}
\subsection{Faktorisierung}
\subsection{Transponierte}
\words % -----------------------------------------
\subsection{Permutationen}

\section{Vektorräume}
\subsection{Kern}
\subsection{Rang}
\subsection{Reduzierte Treppenform}
\subsection{Unabhängigkeit}
\subsection{Basis}
\subsection{Dimension}


\section{Orthogonalität}
\subsection{Projektionen}
\subsection{Kleinste Quadrate}
\words % --------------------------------------------
\subsection{Orthogonale Basen und Gram-Schmidt}

\section{Determinanten}
\subsection{Eigenschaften}
\subsection{Permutationen}
\subsection{Kofaktoren}
\subsection{Cramer'sche Regel}
\subsection{Inverse}
\subsection{Volumen}

\section{Eigenwerte und -vektoren}

\section{Anwendungen}
\words % ------------------------------------------
\section{Numerische lineare Algebra}
\words % ----------------------------------------
\section{Komplexe Vektoren und Matrizen}
\end{document}
```

Adding text below the divisional titles gets everything output. LaTeX is unable to automatically hyphenate your *ThisIsAnOverflowingRootNode* so you have to put in possible
hyphenation points yourself, the `\hyphenation` command. LaTeX will not hyphenate the first word on a line. The fix for this is to put `\hspace{0pt}` before the word.

Comment: The zero-width space before a very wide word at the beginning of the line is needed, but the typed space after it really isn't.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thank you. I have edited my answer to remove the space.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\Huge
\begin{tabular}{p{2cm}p{10cm}}
1.& ThisIsOverflowingRootNote\\
2 & ThisIsAnOverflowingRootNode\\
3 & Vektorrechnung\\
3.1  & L\"{a}ngen\\
3.2 &Skalarprodukte\\
4 &Lineare Gleichungssysteme\\
5&Elimination\\
5.1 & Matrixoperationen\\
5.2 & Inverse Matrizen\\
5.3 & Faktorisierung\\
5.4 &Transponierte\\
5.5 & Permutationen\\

6 & Vektorräume\\
6.1 & Kern\\
6.2 & Rang\\
6.3 & Reduzierte Treppenform\\
6.4 & Unabhängigkeit\\
6,5 & Basis\\
6.6 & Dimension\\
\end{tabular}
\newpage
\begin{tabular}{p{2cm}p{10cm}}
7. & Orthogonalität\\
7.1& Projektionen\\
7.2 & Kleinste Quadrate\\
7.3 & Orthogonale Basen und Gram-Schmidt\\
8.1& Determinanten\\
8.2 & Eigenschaften\\
8.3& Permutationen\\
8.4 & Kofaktoren\\
8.5 & Cramer'sche Regel\\
8.6 & Inverse\\
8.7 & Volumen\\
9 & Eigenwerte und -vektoren\\
10 & Anwendungen\\
11 & Numerische lineare Algebra\\
12 & Komplexe Vektoren und Matrizen\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

This way I modified it. You can change it according your requirements. Thanks.

Comment: This would be better formatted as code.  To do that, highlight it with your mouse, then click on the `{}` icon above the answer box.  (I'm not doing that, since that would put my name on it, and it's really your answer.)

Comment: Is this an answer? How is relates to OP question? It also not works.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\textwidth= 16cm
\begin{document}
\flushleft 
 \Huge 1. This Is Overflowing Root Note\\
 \Huge 2. This Is An Overflowing Root Node\\
 \Huge 3. Vektorrechnung\\ 

\hspace{1cm}{\LARGE{3.1  L\"{a}ngen}\\
\hspace{1cm}{\LARGE{3.2  Skalarprodukte}\\
\Huge  4. Lineare Gleichungssysteme\\
\Huge  5.  Elimination\\
\hspace{1cm}{\LARGE{5.1  Matrixoperationen}}\\
\hspace{1cm}{\LARGE{5.2  Inverse Matrizen}}\\
\hspace{1cm}{\LARGE{5.3  Faktorisierung}}\\
\hspace{1cm}{\LARGE{5.4  Transponierte}}\\
\hspace{1cm}{\LARGE{5.5  Permutationen}}\\
\Huge  6.  Vektorräume\\
\hspace{1cm}{\LARGE{6.1  Kern}}\\
\hspace{1cm}{\LARGE{6.2  Rang}}\\
\hspace{1cm}{\LARGE{6.3  Reduzierte Treppenform}}\\
\hspace{1cm}{\LARGE{6.4  Unabhängigkeit}}\\
\hspace{1cm}{\LARGE{6,5  Basis}}\\
\hspace{1cm}{\Large{6.6  Dimension}}\\
\Huge{7.  Orthogonalität}\\
\hspace{1cm}{\LARGE{7.1 Projektionen}}\\
\hspace{1cm}{\LARGE{7.2 Kleinste Quadrate}}\\
\hspace{1cm}{\LARGE{7.3 Orthogonale Basen und Gram-Schmidt}}\\
\hspace{1cm}{\LARGE{8.1 Determinanten}}\\
\hspace{1cm}{\LARGE{8.2 Eigenschaften}}\\
\hspace{1cm}{\LARGE{8.3 Permutationen}}\\
\hspace{1cm}{\LARGE{8.4 Kofaktoren}}\\
\hspace{1cm}{\LARGE{8.5 Cramer'sche Regel}}\\
\hspace{1cm}{\LARGE{8.6 Inverse}}\\
\hspace{1cm}{\LARGE{8.7 Volumen}}\\
\Huge \hspace{0.1cm} 9. Eigenwerte und -vektoren\\
\Huge 10. Anwendungen\\
\Huge 11. Numerische lineare Algebra\\
\Huge 12. Komplexe Vektoren und Matrizen\\

\end{document}
```

I tried to reduce the overflow. But could not. This occurs when one uses tabular environment. I never worried about it. But I have put your whole table in a new format. This does not give any overflow. I do not know any MWE but they may not help much. One has to learn by trial and error.

Comment: How your answer is relates to OP question?

Comment: Do you really suggest to manually number section headers?

Comment: Yes. This will be nice. Normally \section and sub section gives these numbers. In that case they will not be niced arranged.