# How to avoid columns' text overlapping for the first row in this table?

Tags: tables, formatting, tabularx, typography

The obvious way is by changing the column width, but what I'd like is to get automatically a hyphen at the border for the long word and put the rest of it in a second row (e.g., in the first word Recommended wish to be as Recomm-ended).
By the way, the second word methodologies is hyphenated automatically!
[image]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
 \usepackage{array}
 \newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
 \newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

 \begin{document}

 \begin{table}
 \centering
 \begin{tabular}{|M{1.15cm}|M{2.5cm}|M{2.5cm}|}

 \hline
 Recommended methodologiesy & aa          & bb( \%) \\ \hline
 Classic                 & 3342 voxels & 68 \%   \\ \hline
 VC                      & 4296 voxels & 87 \%   \\ \hline
 V m=7                   & 4745 voxels & 96 \%   \\ \hline
 \end{tabular}
 \newline\newline
 \caption{title}\label{tab1}
 \end{table}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: [Table column text exceeds column width](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/394077)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LaTeX won't hyphenate the first word in a sentence, so you need to cheat a little.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

  \begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|M{1.15cm}|M{2.5cm}|M{2.5cm}|}

      \hline
      \hskip0pt Recommended methodologiesy & aa          & bb( \%) \\ \hline
      Classic                 & 3342 voxels & 68 \%   \\ \hline
      VC                      & 4296 voxels & 87 \%   \\ \hline
      V m=7                   & 4745 voxels & 96 \%   \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \newline\newline
    \caption{title}\label{tab1}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: hyphenated first word]

You should consider reading the `booktabs` manual on the typesetting of professional quality tables.

Comment: Thanks cfr. I got it now, and \hskip0pt helpful for this situation.