# Hyphenate a single word in a column

Tags: tables, tabularx, hyphenation, columns

I would like the first word (i.e. Programming) to be hyphenated, but it is not and it is running into the column beside it. I'm thinking that since it is a standalone word, LaTeX is trying to avoid hyphenating it?

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{array,tabularx}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabularx}{2in}{@{}p{0.3in}@{\hspace{3ex}}X@{}}
        Programming &  Python, MATLAB, R, FORTRAN\\
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
%  also tried this in place of p column: >{\raggedright\hsize=6ex\arraybackslash}X
Also tried removing @{\hspace{3ex}} between columns
```

Comment: Adding `\hspace{0pt}` as `\hspace{0pt}Programming` should work. However, the result might look not that pleasing since `0.3in` is extremely small for such a column. What's the reason for such a narrow table?

Comment: I have removed the `paracolumns` tag since I did not see any connection between your example and text in parallelly typeset columns.

Comment: Potential duplicate: [Table column text exceeds column width](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/394077)

Comment: @leandriis, perfect thank you. I'm playing around with a resume template.