# Table - Resize table and automatic line breaks

Tags: tables, tabularx

I have the table below.

```
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|}
\hline
\textbf{Cache Configuration} &
  \textbf{Access Latency (ns)} &
  \textbf{Overhead} &
  \textbf{Dynamic Read Energy (nJ)} &
  \textbf{Overhead} &
  \textbf{Leakage Power (mW)} &
  \textbf{Overhead} &
  \textbf{Area (mm2)} &
  \textbf{Overhead} \\ \hline
Conventional Cache (1MB)           & 1.3125 &      & 0.3295 &      & 221.796  &      & 3.4085  &      \\ \hline
Conventional Cache (8MB)           & 2.7504 &      & 0.8605 &      & 1641.11  &      & 18.7754 &      \\ \hline
Frequency Table (FT)               & 0.4129 &      & 0.0008 &      & 2.4785   &      & 0.0296  &      \\ \hline
Precompression Table (PT)          & 0.6353 &      & 0.0014 &      & 4.9366   &      & 0.0788  &      \\ \hline
Mapping Table (MT)                 & 0.0927 &      & 0.0011 &      & 0.3396   &      & 0.0032  &      \\ \hline
Overflow Mapping Table             & 0.3394 &      & 0.0020 &      & 4.5186   &      & 0.038   &      \\ \hline
Precompression-enabled Cache (1MB) & 2.2873 & 74\% & 0.4178 & 26\% & 273.539  & 23\% & 3.9191  & 15\% \\ \hline
Precompression-enabled Cache (8MB) & 3.7251 & 35\% & 0.9489 & 10\% & 1692.853 & 3\%  & 19.2859 & 5\%  \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
}
\caption{Access Latency, Energy, Power and Area Overheads of Precompression logic and Precompression-enabled caches.}
\label{table:precompression-overhead}
\end{table}
```

[image: Table Output]

I have tried different techniques, but I can't seem to make it work. I want the table to fit in the page, along with automatic line breaks that don't break words with hyphens (maybe except for the Overhead columns).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please extend you code fragment to complete small document which reproduce your table,. We havent any information about used document class nor page layout.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Zarko. The document class is defined in a separate class file. What would be the best way to include that without having it take the entire page?

Comment: @vic If you could just add the `\documentclass[...]{...}` line and all other lines from the preamble that affect the code you're having problems with (so for example here it would be `\usepackage{tabularx}`, and maybe some more if you loaded extra packages or changed commands that change how your table behaves), that would be optimal.

Comment: Although it's not an elegant solution, allowing "Overhead" to be hyphenated would remove the overfull lines in the table header. The first word in a paragraph is not hyphenated; this is a design feature of TeX. Hyphenation can be accomplished by preceding the first word by `\hspace{0pt}` as shown in this question: [Table column text exceeds column width](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/394077)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Or using tabulary, or using Ragged... from ragged2e.

Comment: No one has mentioned it, but the caption would look a whole lot nicer if it were set ragged right.

Answer (score 5):

**First** off, do observe that the `\resizebox{\textwidth}{...}` "wrapper" serves no useful purpose since the width of the command's second argument is equal `\textwidth`. In fact, the way you set up the wrapper, it is actually slightly counterproductive. Why? Your code is a follows:

```
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|}
...
\end{tabularx}
}
```

So what exactly is the problem, you may ask? It's the fact that you didn't terminate the line

```
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
```

with a `%` (comment) symbol. As a result, the *total width* of the material governed by `\resizebox` is not just `\textwidth` but `\textwidth` plus 1 interword space. The correct way to write the instruction is like this:

```
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
```

However, as argued above, the `\resizebox` wrapper is superfluous to begin with and should be omitted.

**Second**, I suggest you continue to use a `tabularx` environment, but use a narrower width for the "Overhead" column than for the other columns. In the solution below, the four "overhead" columns are 40% narrower than the other four data columns. When setting up varying-width columns of type `X`, the cardinal rule is that the sum of the relative widths -- 4*1.25+4*0.75 -- must equal the number of columns of type `X` -- here: 8.

**Third**, I would try hard to give a the a much more open "look", mainly by omitting all vertical rules and using fewer, but well-spaced, horizontal rules.

**Lastly**, I'd left-align the first column and center-set all 8 data columns.

---

Here's the proposed modification and the associated screenshot:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,hmargin=1in]{geometry} % set page parameters suitably
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
% set up a modified, i.e., centered version of the "X" column type:
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering\arraybackslash%
     \hsize=#1\hsize\linewidth=\hsize\hspace{0pt}}X}

% determine width and column type of first column:
\newlength\mylen
\settowidth\mylen{enabled Cache (8MB)} 
\newcolumntype{M}{>{\RaggedRight}m{\mylen}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt} % default: 6pt
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} M *{4}{C{1.25}C{0.75}} @{}}
\toprule
  \textbf{Cache Configuration} &
  \textbf{Access Latency} (ns) &
  \textbf{Overhead} &
  \textbf{Dynamic Read Energy} (nJ) &
  \textbf{Overhead} &
  \textbf{Leakage Power} (mW) &
  \textbf{Overhead} &
  \textbf{Area} (mm\textsuperscript{2}) &
  \textbf{Overhead} \\ 
\midrule
Conventional Cache (1MB)           & 1.3125 &      & 0.3295 &      & 221.796  &      & 3.4085  &      \\ \addlinespace
Conventional Cache (8MB)           & 2.7504 &      & 0.8605 &      & 1641.11  &      & 18.7754 &      \\ \addlinespace
Frequency Table (FT)               & 0.4129 &      & 0.0008 &      & 2.4785   &      & 0.0296  &      \\ \addlinespace
Precompression Table (PT)          & 0.6353 &      & 0.0014 &      & 4.9366   &      & 0.0788  &      \\ \addlinespace
Mapping Table (MT)                 & 0.0927 &      & 0.0011 &      & 0.3396   &      & 0.0032  &      \\ \addlinespace
Overflow Mapping Table             & 0.3394 &      & 0.0020 &      & 4.5186   &      & 0.038   &      \\ \addlinespace
Precompression-enabled Cache (1MB) & 2.2873 & 74\% & 0.4178 & 26\% & 273.539  & 23\% & 3.9191  & 15\% \\ \addlinespace
Precompression-enabled Cache (8MB) & 3.7251 & 35\% & 0.9489 & 10\% & 1692.853 & 3\%  & 19.2859 & 5\%  \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Access Latency, Energy, Power and Area Overheads of Precompression logic and Precompression-enabled caches.}
\label{table:precompression-overhead}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a possible solution using the package [tabulary](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabulary) instead of [tabularx](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx). I have also loaded babel to have automatic hyphenation of ‘Overhead’. Also, I loaded [geometry](https://ctan.org/pkg/geometry), because I assumed that you have more sensible margins in your real document. The font size is reduced to `\footnotesize`, and then you have a readable tabular that fits inside sensible margins.

Of cause, I suggest setting the tabular using [booktabs](https://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) and no vertical rules, see examples 1 and 3 below. The per cent sign (%) should be moved from the column to the heading.

The (updatred) example 1 uses fixed width `x`-columns in combination with tabular*. Headings are set in a nested tabular and line breakes are set manually using `\\`. You may use `\parbox` instead of the tabulars. Font size for headings are reduces two grades, to `\footnotesize`, rest of the tabular's text and figures are in normal font size (10 pt). I have aligned the heading at the bottom, because that is according to the recommendation in my part of the word.

If you have the right to restructure the tabular, I suggest that you move the four overhead columns to two new *rows* with a description what the overheads refer to (comparing conventional caches and pre-compression enabled caches?)

**Example 1 - tabular***

[image]

```
\documentclass[UKenglish]{article}
\usepackage{array, tabulary, booktabs, lmodern}
\usepackage{babel, caption}
\usepackage{geometry}



% Multi-line left-aligned text with manual line breaks.
% The base line of the whole is at the top row.
\newcommand*{\tstack}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{0.85}%
    \footnotesize\bfseries\begin{tabular}[b]{c}#1\end{tabular}%
  \endgroup
}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
\caption{Access Latency, Energy, Power and Area Overheads of Precompression logic and Precompression-enabled caches.}
\label{table:precompression-overhead}

\centering
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                                                l
                                                wr{1.2cm}
                                                wr{0.9cm}
                                                wr{1.45cm}
                                                wr{0.9cm}
                                                wr{1.55cm}
                                                wr{0.95cm}
                                                wr{1.4cm}
                                                wr{0.9cm}
                                                }
\toprule
\tstack{Cache Configuration} &
\tstack{Access\\ Latency\\ \scriptsize (ns)} &
\tstack{Over-\\head \\\scriptsize(\%)} &
\tstack{Dynamic\\Read\\ Energy\\ \scriptsize(nJ)} &
\tstack{Over-\\head\\\scriptsize(\%)} &
\tstack{Leakage \\Power\\ \scriptsize(mW)} &
\tstack{Over-\\head\\\scriptsize(\%)} &
\tstack{Area\\\scriptsize(mm\textsuperscript{2})} &
\tstack{Over-\\head\\\scriptsize(\%)} 
\\ \midrule
Conventional Cache (1MB)           & 1.3125 &      & 0.3295 &      & 221.796  &      & 3.4085  &      \\ 
Conventional Cache (8MB)           & 2.7504 &      & 0.8605 &      & 1641.110  &      & 18.7754 &      \\
Frequency Table (FT)               & 0.4129 &      & 0.0008 &      & 2.4785   &      & 0.0296  &      \\ Precompression Table (PT)          & 0.6353 &      & 0.0014 &      & 4.9366   &      & 0.0788  &      \\ 
Mapping Table (MT)                 & 0.0927 &      & 0.0011 &      & 0.3396   &      & 0.0032  &      \\ 
Overflow Mapping Table             & 0.3394 &      & 0.0020 &      & 4.5186   &      & 0.038   &      \\
Precompression-enabled Cache (1MB) & 2.2873 & 74  & 0.4178 & 26  & 273.539  & 23  & 3.9191  & 15  \\ 
Precompression-enabled Cache (8MB) & 3.7251 & 35  & 0.9489 & 10  & 1692.853 & 3   & 19.2859 & 5  \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

**Example 2**

[image]

```
\documentclass[UKenglish]{article}
\usepackage{array, tabulary, booktabs}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}


\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{|L|R|R|R|R|R|R|R|R|}
\hline
\textbf{Cache Configuration} &
  \textbf{Access Latency (ns)} &
  \textbf{Overhead (\%)} &
  \textbf{Dynamic Read Energy (nJ)} &
  \textbf{Overhead (\%)} &
  \textbf{Leakage Power (mW)} &
  \textbf{Overhead (\%)} &
  \textbf{Area (mm2)} &
  \textbf{Overhead} \\ \hline
Conventional Cache (1MB)           & 1.3125 &      & 0.3295 &      & 221.796  &      & 3.4085  &      \\ \hline
Conventional Cache (8MB)           & 2.7504 &      & 0.8605 &      & 1641.11  &      & 18.7754 &      \\ \hline
Frequency Table (FT)               & 0.4129 &      & 0.0008 &      & 2.4785   &      & 0.0296  &      \\ \hline
Precompression Table (PT)          & 0.6353 &      & 0.0014 &      & 4.9366   &      & 0.0788  &      \\ \hline
Mapping Table (MT)                 & 0.0927 &      & 0.0011 &      & 0.3396   &      & 0.0032  &      \\ \hline
Overflow Mapping Table             & 0.3394 &      & 0.0020 &      & 4.5186   &      & 0.038   &      \\ \hline
Precompression-enabled Cache (1MB) & 2.2873 & 74  & 0.4178 & 26  & 273.539  & 23  & 3.9191  & 15  \\ \hline
Precompression-enabled Cache (8MB) & 3.7251 & 35  & 0.9489 & 10  & 1692.853 & 3   & 19.2859 & 5  \\ \hline
\end{tabulary}
\caption{Access Latency, Energy, Power and Area Overheads of Precompression logic and Precompression-enabled caches.}
\label{table:precompression-overhead}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

**Example 3 - booktabs and tabulary**

[image]

```
\documentclass[UKenglish]{article}
\usepackage{array, tabulary, booktabs}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}


\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
\centering\footnotesize

\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{@{}L*{8}{R}@{}}
\toprule
\textbf{Cache Configuration} &
  \centering\textbf{Access Latency (ns)} &
  \textbf{Overhead (\%)} &
  \centering\textbf{Dynamic Read Energy (nJ)} &
  \textbf{Overhead(\%)} &
  \centering\textbf{Leakage Power (mW)} &
  \textbf{Overhead (\%)} &
  \centering\textbf{Area (mm2)} &
  \textbf{Overhead (\%)} 
\\ \midrule
Conventional Cache (1MB)           & 1.3125 &      & 0.3295 &      & 221.796  &      & 3.4085  &      \\ 
Conventional Cache (8MB)           & 2.7504 &      & 0.8605 &      & 1641.110  &      & 18.7754 &      \\
Frequency Table (FT)               & 0.4129 &      & 0.0008 &      & 2.4785   &      & 0.0296  &      \\ Precompression Table (PT)          & 0.6353 &      & 0.0014 &      & 4.9366   &      & 0.0788  &      \\ \midrule
Mapping Table (MT)                 & 0.0927 &      & 0.0011 &      & 0.3396   &      & 0.0032  &      \\ 
Overflow Mapping Table             & 0.3394 &      & 0.0020 &      & 4.5186   &      & 0.038   &      \\
Precompression-enabled Cache (1MB) & 2.2873 & 74  & 0.4178 & 26  & 273.539  & 23  & 3.9191  & 15  \\ 
Precompression-enabled Cache (8MB) & 3.7251 & 35  & 0.9489 & 10  & 1692.853 & 3   & 19.2859 & 5  \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabulary}
\caption{Access Latency, Energy, Power and Area Overheads of Precompression logic and Precompression-enabled caches.}
\label{table:precompression-overhead}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Based on guessing about your document layout. One way to avoid overlapping is use rotated column headers:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn,10pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\footnotesize}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\small
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\makegapedcells
\settowidth\rotheadsize{\theadfont Dynamic Read} 
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{\raggedright}X|S[table-format=1.4]|c|
                                S[table-format=1.4]|c|
                                S[table-format=4.4]|c|
                                S[table-format=2.4]|c|}
\hline
\thead{Cache\\ Configuration} &
  \rothead{Access Latency (ns)} &
  \rothead{Overhead} &
  \rothead{Dynamic Read Energy (nJ)} &
  \rothead{Overhead} &
  \rothead{Leakage Power (mW)} &
  \rothead{Overhead} &
  \rothead{Area (mm2)} &
  \rothead{Overhead} \\ \hline
Conventional Cache (1MB)           & 1.3125 &      & 0.3295 &      & 221.796  &      & 3.4085  &      \\ \hline
Conventional Cache (8MB)           & 2.7504 &      & 0.8605 &      & 1641.11  &      & 18.7754 &      \\ \hline
Frequency Table (FT)               & 0.4129 &      & 0.0008 &      & 2.4785   &      & 0.0296  &      \\ \hline
Precompression Table (PT)          & 0.6353 &      & 0.0014 &      & 4.9366   &      & 0.0788  &      \\ \hline
Mapping Table (MT)                 & 0.0927 &      & 0.0011 &      & 0.3396   &      & 0.0032  &      \\ \hline
Overflow Mapping Table             & 0.3394 &      & 0.0020 &      & 4.5186   &      & 0.038   &      \\ \hline
Precompression-enabled Cache (1MB) & 2.2873 & 74\% & 0.4178 & 26\% & 273.539  & 23\% & 3.9191  & 15\% \\ \hline
Precompression-enabled Cache (8MB) & 3.7251 & 35\% & 0.9489 & 10\% & 1692.853 & 3\%  & 19.2859 & 5\%  \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}

\caption{Access Latency, Energy, Power and Area Overheads of Precompression logic and Precompression-enabled caches.}
\label{table:precompression-overhead}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or when the `\textwidth` is smaller:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn,10pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\footnotesize}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\small
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\makegapedcells
\settowidth\rotheadsize{\theadfont Dynamic Read} 
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{\raggedright}X|
                                S[table-format=1.4]|c|
                                S[table-format=1.4]|c|
                                S[table-format=4.4]|c|
                                S[table-format=2.4]|c|}
\hline
\thead{Cache\\ Configuration} &
  \rothead{Access Latency (ns)} &
  \rothead{Overhead} &
  \rothead{Dynamic Read Energy (nJ)} &
  \rothead{Overhead} &
  \rothead{Leakage Power (mW)} &
  \rothead{Overhead} &
  \rothead{Area (mm2)} &
  \rothead{Overhead} \\ \hline
Conventional Cache (1MB)           & 1.3125 &      & 0.3295 &      & 221.796  &      & 3.4085  &      \\ \hline
Conventional Cache (8MB)           & 2.7504 &      & 0.8605 &      & 1641.11  &      & 18.7754 &      \\ \hline
Frequency Table (FT)               & 0.4129 &      & 0.0008 &      & 2.4785   &      & 0.0296  &      \\ \hline
Precompression Table (PT)          & 0.6353 &      & 0.0014 &      & 4.9366   &      & 0.0788  &      \\ \hline
Mapping Table (MT)                 & 0.0927 &      & 0.0011 &      & 0.3396   &      & 0.0032  &      \\ \hline
Overflow Mapping Table             & 0.3394 &      & 0.0020 &      & 4.5186   &      & 0.038   &      \\ \hline
Precompression-enabled Cache (1MB) & 2.2873 & 74\% & 0.4178 & 26\% & 273.539  & 23\% & 3.9191  & 15\% \\ \hline
Precompression-enabled Cache (8MB) & 3.7251 & 35\% & 0.9489 & 10\% & 1692.853 & 3\%  & 19.2859 & 5\%  \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}

\caption{Access Latency, Energy, Power and Area Overheads of Precompression logic and Precompression-enabled caches.}
\label{table:precompression-overhead}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your solution Zarko. What would be the way to have all the values in the Leakage Power and Area columns be right aligned?

Comment: Column 8 is too narrow. You should also move the per cent sign to the headings in column 3, column 5, column 7 and column 9.

Comment: @Sveinung, thank you very much for pointing me to error in last `S` column definitions.  Regarding `%`, I left them as OP writes them in his code fragment, however I agrree with you.

Answer (score 0):

I propose this variant, using a basic `tabular` and the possibilities of `makecell`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, fleqn, 10pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\footnotesize}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\newrobustcmd{\myrothead}[1]{\rotatebox[origin=l]{30}{\rlap{#1}}\hfill\null}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
\centering
\small
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\small}
\renewcommand{\cellset}{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.6}}
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\makegapedcells
\settowidth\rotheadsize{\theadfont Dynamic Read}
\sisetup{table-text-alignment=left}
\begin{tabular}{!{\vline width 1pt} l|S[table-format=1.4, table-text-alignment=left]|c|
                                S[table-format=1.4]|c|
                                S[table-format=4.4]|c|
                                S[table-format=2.4]|c!{\vline width 1pt}}
\noalign{\vskip4ex}
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\raisebox{-1.5ex}{\thead[bl]{Cache\\ Configuration}}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{\myrothead{\makecell[tl]{Access Latency\\[-1ex] (ns)}}}&
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{\myrothead{\raisebox{-1.5ex}{Overhead}}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{\myrothead{\makecell[tl]{Dynamic Read\\[-1ex] Energy (nJ)}}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{\myrothead{\raisebox{-1.5ex}{Overhead}}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{\myrothead{\makecell[tl]{Leakage Power\\[-1ex] (mW)}}} &
 \multicolumn{1}{l}{\myrothead{\raisebox{-1.5ex}{Overhead}}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{\myrothead{\raisebox{-1.5ex}{Area (mm2)}}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{\myrothead{\raisebox{-1.5ex}{Overhead}}} \\ \Xhline{1pt}
\makecell[l]{Conventional \\Cache (1MB)} & 1.3125 & & 0.3295 & & 221.796 & & 3.4085 & \\ \hline
\makecell[l]{Conventional\\ Cache (8MB)} & 2.7504 & & 0.8605 & & 1641.11 & & 18.7754 & \\ \hline
\makecell[l]{Frequency Table\\ (FT)} & 0.4129 & & 0.0008 & & 2.4785 & & 0.0296 & \\ \hline
\makecell[l]{Precompression Table\\ (PT)} & 0.6353 & & 0.0014 & & 4.9366 & & 0.0788 & \\ \hline
\makecell[l]{Mapping Table\\ (MT)} & 0.0927 & & 0.0011 & & 0.3396 & & 0.0032 & \\ \hline
\makecell[l]{Overflow\\ Mapping Table} & 0.3394 & & 0.0020 & & 4.5186 & & 0.038 & \\ \hline
\makecell[l]{Precompression-enabled\\ Cache (1MB)} & 2.2873 & 74\% & 0.4178 & 26\% & 273.539 & 23\% & 3.9191 & 15\% \\ \hline
\makecell[l]{Precompression-enabled\\ Cache (8MB)} & 3.7251 & 35\% & 0.9489 & 10\% & 1692.853 & 3\% & 19.2859 & 5\% \\ \Xhline{1pt}
\end{tabular}
%
\caption{Access Latency, Energy, Power and Area Overheads of Precompression logic and Precompression-enabled caches.}
\label{table:precompression-overhead}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]