# Some text wrapping and some not in table

Tags: tables, spacing, formatting

I've created a very big table using https://www.tablesgenerator.com/latex_tables and need to wrap text so that the table fits on the page. After consulting this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/790932/how-to-wrap-text-in-latex-tables, I've managed to wrap some but not all of text in the table. I've had a look at this question to see what else I need to do ([Table column text exceeds column width](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/394077/table-column-text-exceeds-column-width)) but, due to my inexperience, I can't work out what I need to do in my case. Thanks!

Here's the beginning of the code for the table:

```
% Please add the following required packages to your document preamble:
% \usepackage{booktabs}
% \usepackage{multirow}
% \usepackage{lscape}
% \usepackage{longtable}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}{p{0.15\linewidth} p{0.25\linewidth} p{0.25\linewidth} p{0.25\linewidth}}
\caption{Summary of Searing's Backbench Preference Roles}
\label{Searing Summary}\\
\toprule
\textbf{(Sub-)Role   (\% in House of Commons or \% of parent role)} &
  \textbf{(Absence of) Activity} &
  \textbf{Trends (and cause(s))} &
  \textbf{Role Choice Influenced by:} \\* \midrule
\endhead
%
\cmidrule(lr){2-2}
\endfoot
%
\endlastfoot
%
\multirow{6}{*}{Policy Advocate (40)} &
  \multirow{6}{*}{} &
  \multirow{6}{*}{·   Increasing prevalence over time (linked to professionalisation of MPs and decrease in working class Labour MPs and Conservative Knights of   the Shire, rise of professional lobbying, new facilities and changes to committee system).} &
  ·   Age (too old to gain a ministerial position); \\
 &
   &
   &
  ·   Demand among electorate   for constituency service (Proportion of policy advocates decreases as   constituency class composition becomes increasingly heterogenous); \\
 &
   &
   &
  ·   Electoral security   (especially important for Specialists; the safer the seat, the more likely an   MP is to be a Policy Advocate); \\
```

Comment: rather than upping everything I  suggest a few rows which are troublesome -- it would be easier to understand

Comment: Sorry - have edited the above. The first entry in the table that is problematic is "Increasing prevalence over time..." in the third table, even though everything is wrapping is at should in the fourth column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? Note: no use for `\multirow`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}  % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pdflscape,longtable,booktabs,array,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight}p{#1\linewidth}} % handy shortcut macro
% Create a bespoke itemize-like list environment:
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{myitemize}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[myitemize,1]{label=\textbullet,nosep,wide=0pt,
                      before={\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}},
                      after={\end{minipage}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}{@{} P{0.15} P{0.25} P{0.25} P{0.25} @{}}
\caption{Summary of Searing's Backbench Preference Roles}
\label{Searing Summary}\\
\toprule
\textbf{(Sub-)Role (\%~in House of Commons or \%~of parent role)} &
\textbf{(Absence of) Activity} &
\textbf{Trends (and cause(s))} &
\textbf{Role choice influenced by} \\ 
\midrule
\endhead
%
\cmidrule(lr){2-2}
\endfoot
%
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot
%
Policy Advocate (40) & 
\dots &
\begin{myitemize}
\item Increasing prevalence over time (linked to professionalisation of 
  MPs and decrease in working class Labour MPs and Conservative Knights of   
  the Shire, rise of professional lobbying, new facilities and changes to 
  committee system). 
\end{myitemize} &
\begin{myitemize}
\item Age (too old to gain a ministerial position)
\end{myitemize} \\
\dots &
\dots &
\dots &
\begin{myitemize}
\item Demand among electorate for constituency service (Proportion of 
  policy advocates decreases as constituency class composition becomes 
  increasingly heterogenous); 
\item Electoral security (especially important for Specialists; the 
  safer the seat, the more likely an MP is to be a Policy Advocate);
\end{myitemize} \\
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! This has worked well. Much appreciated for your time.